# Using eval to execute functions

Tags: javascript

There is something I don't understand about how eval works.
Suppose I have a function foo:

```
function foo() {
    console.log("test");
}
```

And then I write

```
eval("foo()");
```

or

```
eval("foo" + "();");
```

The function foo is executed and I have "test" printed out.
However, if I write:

```
eval("function foo() { console.log(\"foo\"); }();");
```

or

```
eval("function foo() { console.log(\"foo\"); }" + "();");
```

I get "SyntaxError: Unexpected token )".
Why is that? I saw that when I pass the function name it is evaluated into the function's code, so I though it's supposed to be the same as "eval("foo" + "();");"

I'm using Chrome 27 if it makes any difference.

Comment: `eval` is meant to evaluate expressions, the last example isn't a single expression. Add an operator to the function declaration and you're there. That said `eval`-ing code like this is a _terrible idea_, so I'd suggest _not_ to even begin to try and understand how it works

Comment: actually, `eval` is totally irrelevant here - that code will fail just in the same way without it.

Comment: @thg435: Yes, it will. In my answer I went into more detail, and explained why his last `eval` call actually contained a syntactically invalid statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because no answer is specific about *why* the last snippet fails, and nobody seems to be warning you for the dangers of `eval`:

`eval`, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval):

> A string representing a JavaScript expression, statement, or sequence of statements. The expression can include variables and properties of existing objects.

Your string, `"function foo(){console.log('foo');}()"` actually consists of 2 statements, that make no sense to the JS engine. Well, the second one doesn't:

```
function foo(){console.log('foo');}//function declaration, fine
;//<-- js adds implied statement terminator
()//no invocation, because no function reference, group nothing ==> does not compute, raise error
```

That's why you *have* to turn your function declaration statement into an expression, by adding an operator. Typically, this is the grouping operator: `()`

```
(function foo(){ console.log('foo')});
```

The function declaration is now an expression, everything (the grouping `()` included) can be seen as a statement, unless the code that follows belongs to the code above. In this case, the invoking parentheses clearly do, so the JS engine sorts it out for you.
For clarity, some say the preferred notation is:

```
(function f(){}());//<-- invoking parentheses inside group
```

Which makes sense, because the invocation is part of the statement, after all.

If you don't like all these parentheses, any operator will do:

```
~function(){}();//bitwise not
+function(){}();//coerce to number
```

Are all equally valid. Note that they *will* change the possible return values of the function expression.

```
(function(){}());//resolves to undefined
+function(){}();//resolves to NaN, because undefined is NotANumber
```

How your `eval` could look, then, is any of the following:

```
eval("(function (){console.log('foo');}());");
eval("~function (){console.log('foo');}();");
eval("!function (){console.log('foo');}();");
```

And so on, and so forth...

Lastly, `eval` evaluates code in the global scope, so any code `eval`-ed containing functions can, and likely will, polute the global namespace. Mallicious code will also have access to *everything*, so be weary of XSS attacks and all other JS based techniques.
Bottom line, `eval` is **evil**, especially since all browsers now support `JSON.parse` natively, and for those that don't, there still is a tried and tested JSON2.js file out there.
Using `eval` in strict mode does make things slightly safer, but doesn't prevent XSS attacks at all, the code can still manipulate the DOM, for example, and reassign exposed DOM references or objects.

Google *"why eval is evil"* if you want to find out more.
Also [check the *ECMAScript* specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.2)

Comment: `()//invoke what? does not compute, raise error` I actually think that this is interpreted as the grouping operator as well, but it cannot be empty. The syntax error is `SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`. If you replace `()` with `(1)` it works fine. Anyways, +1 for a thorough answer :)

Comment: @FelixKling, You're absolutely right... Because of what the OP was trying, I only looked at those parentheses as the way to invoke a function, will edit

Answer (score 1):

```
eval("(function() { console.log(\"foo\"); })()");
```

This is called a self-executing anonymous function.

Comment: `foo` in `function foo()` is not necessary ;-)

Comment: Right, since it's anonymous. I just copied the above and put brackets around it. (edited above)

Comment: Your answer is rather cryptic -- did you modify the code or copy it verbatim? How could I know without checking every single character? It looks like you just copied the code and says "this is what we call this" without explaining anything at all.

Comment: @guy777: It can be: `(function foo(){ if (something === true){ something = false; setTimeout(foo, 1000);} alert('I was called with a timeout');}())`. Instead of using `arguments.callee`, which is deprecated, a named function expression can be used, which doesn't pollute the global namespace

Answer (score 1):

`function x() {}` is a statement, whereas everything else you're doing is an expression, and you can only evaluate expressions.

The other answers explain how you can turn this statement into an expression. Thought I'd let you know why you actually get an error, though. :)

Comment: *"you can only evaluate expressions"* No, that's not true. `eval("function foo() { console.log(\"foo\"); }");` or `eval('if (true){alert(1);}')` is perfectly fine. The problem is that `function foo(){...}()` is just invalid JavaScript.

Comment: You're right, although I still think trying to evaluate a statement is silly, but I guess js doesn't have a big distinction between statements and expressions like some languages do.

Comment: They are two separate chapters in the [specification](http://es5.github.io/) (11 and 12) though I cannot say how their distinction compares to other languages.

Answer (score 0):

you would need to call

```
eval("function foo() { console.log(\"foo\"); };" + " foo();");
```

in order for this to work;

Comment: I think your answer would be more useful if you explained _why_, rather than just adding a character somewhere in the code. Can you explain how your code fixed the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Put brackets around your function

```
eval("(function foo() { console.log(\"foo\"); })()");
```

It is like calling

```
(function foo() { console.log("foo"); })()
```

Answer (score -2):

The main thing you should understand about eval is that it is evil.  Don't use it... ever.  There is always a way to achieve the same thing by dynamically creating a script document or by using a closure.

Read Douglas Crockford: JavaScript the good parts.

Comment: `eval` has to be handled with care, yes, but that was not the question.

Comment: The question had already been answered.  I was just sticking my two pence worth in.  Didn't expect the Q&A police to arrest me for it. :-)

Comment: `eval` isn't evil. It's a tool, and it has its uses. It is true that when used incorrectly it can cause all kinds of problems, but that doesn't make it evil.

Comment: Well, since it doesn't *answer* the question (and you didn't even intend to), maybe you should have written a comment instead.

Comment: evaluated code is not compiled, so it will inevitably slow down execution.  If placed in a loop, the effect is exponential.  As I said, there are better ways to execute dynamic code.  If you are not writing production quality code, then it is absolutely fine.  However, prototyping in the real world doesn't actually exist.  Inevitably, what you prototype will become production implementation.  Scripting languages were invented for RAD, otherwise we would still be stuck with compilation and strict types.