# Javascript creating class object from string

Tags: javascript

Say I had a class defined within a string like the following:

```js
`class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
  
  get area() {
    return this.calcArea();
  }

  calcArea() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
}`
```

Is it possible to turn the string into a javascript class so I could run the following? Or similar..

```js
const square = new Rectangle(10, 10);
console.log(square.area);
```

Comment: have you tried `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: You can do exactly what you want if you just omit the quotation marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn a string into a class if you pass it to `eval`, like this:

```
eval("function MyClass(params) {/*Some code*/}");
var foo = new MyClass({a: 1, b: 2});
```

EDIT:

Based on comments I found out that the syntax shown in the question is ok, but it seems to be incompatible with `eval` as it is. However, doing some experiments I found the following trick:

```
eval("window['Rectangle'] = class Rectangle {constructor(height, width) {this.height = height;this.width = width;}get area() {return this.calcArea();}calcArea() {return this.height * this.width;}}");

var r = new Rectangle(50, 40);
```

Comment: It is valid syntax - see `prototype methods` section  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: Great, but I doesn't look like that works with class declarations. Might be able to work around with functions though...

Comment: The syntax is perfectly fine

Comment: @DarrenSweeney indeed, I was wrong from that point of view, I have edited the answer.

Comment: @RyanKing yes, it just evaluated it and later it could not be used. However, I found a trick, which is a methodology you could achieve what you want with minimal changes.

Comment: Interesting, thanks @LajosArpad, it does the trick! Although I feel Badis Merabet's response has a slightly cleaner approach.

Comment: @RyanKing, you are welcome. The other answer's approach is almost the same as mine, the difference is that the other approach renamed your class.

Comment: @ Ryan King, @LajosArpad, the difference of my answer is not in renaming the class. but in the usage of parentheses around  the class instead of adding a keyword "function" or making an assignment of class to "window" array. but that's fine to accept LajosArpad's answer since it solves the issue first :), still it's less elegant. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a duplicate of this : [Using eval method to get class from string in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39298985/using-eval-method-to-get-class-from-string-in-firefox)

Don't forget to put class between parentheses.

```
var class_str = `(class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }

  get area() {
    return this.calcArea();
  }

  calcArea() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
})`;
var a = eval(class_str);
console.log(new a(10, 10));
```

A working demo here: http://jsbin.com/netipuluki/edit?js,console