# Unit Testing ES6 Class with External Dependency

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, mocha.js

I'm trying to set a unit testing boilerplate for my company. Our front end projects are built with ES6 classes and have a dependency to our core product. The front end code gets wrapped through a build process in a whole other block of code that is basically a closure and captures the dependency. So we don't have to manually import it in order to use it.

Let's say the dependency is called `productScope` and it's an object that has some DOM models, internal APIs and parameters among many other things necessary for each project. At the moment, Mocha throws `ReferenceError: productScope is not defined.` How can I mock this object? Or should I just use the actual object?

Example:

```
class someClass {
    constructor() {
        const id = productScope.items[0].id
        const item = productScope.domModel.querySelector('.some-div')

        item.classList.add(`added-${id}`)
    }
}
```

This get wrapped in core code like below:

```
(function(productScope) {
    // front end code goes here
}(productScope)
```

Testing file:

```
import someClass from '../../js/someClass'

describe('someClass', function() {
    const someClass = new someClass()
    it('should be a class', function() {
        console.log(someClass)
    });
});
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include relevant parts of your unit test code

Comment: Here is an answer that is in the style of your question: Read this: https://gofreerange.com/mocha/docs/Mocha/Mock.html

Comment: @PatrickHund added some code

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
describe('#someClass', () => {
    let someClass;

    beforeEach(() => {
        global.productScope = {
            // mocking productScope object
        };
    });

    it('should be a class', () => {
        someClass = new SomeClass;
        console.log(someClass);
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        delete global.productScope;
    });
});
```

or alternatively if you want more specific mock logic for each test case

```
describe('#someClass', () => {
    let someClass;

    it('should be a class', () => {
        global.productScope = {
            // mocking productScope object
        };

        // Test logic start

        someClass = new SomeClass;
        console.log(someClass);

        // Test logic end

        delete global.productScope;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `productScope` is a global variable.

Something like this should work for you.

```
import someClass from '../../js/someClass';

describe('someClass', function() {
    let someClass;

    beforeEach(() => {
        global.productScope = {
          // you mock definition
          someClass = new someClass();
        };
    });

    it('should be a class', function() {
        console.log(someClass)
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but still the same error, plus `1) "before each" hook for "should be a class"` message in red.

Comment: Where are you getting `productScope` from? Are you importing it in your file or is it a global variable?

Comment: Basically, there is a whole block of code that wraps the front end code, and it's a closure that captures `productScope`

Comment: If it's a closure, you could stub it with `sinon`. Can you show how you import `productScope` in the `js/someClass` file?

Comment: I don’t need to import it to the class because the class is kind of wrapped in it. Perhaps like how you’d use the $ as jQuery inside of an IIFE.

Comment: Looks like you have a complicated code setup. Can you add the entire code for clarity?

Answer (score 0):

I'm with other answers as well, as managing `global` variables seems to be the simplest and most straightforward solution.

However, you can use [toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) to get class's string representation, and [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) it to bind to closure's scope:

```js
class someClass {
   constructor() {
     this.id = scopedId
   }
}

// pass class as an argument
function scopeFactory(classDef) {

   // define scoped data
   let scopedId = 2;

   // eval is used to bind class to the local closure
   // so `scopedId` will be in charge
   return eval("(" + classDef + ")");
}

const scopedSomeClass = scopeFactory(someClass);

console.log(new scopedSomeClass)
```

Note that `eval(someCLass.toString())` [doesn't work without parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39298985/using-eval-method-to-get-class-from-string-in-firefox).

You can add it as a helper function, into your project.